# how can I copy postgresql databases between two AWS RDS db instances (in different VPC but same region)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have created a AWS RDS Postgresql db instance in one VPC and I need to "move" it to another VPC.
I created a snapshot of the original db instance.
Re-created it in a new VPC (using terraform).

How can I retrieve one particular database from my initial db instance snapshot into the new DB Instance?

Answer (score 0):

When you restore snapshot all databases are restored. 
If you want to copy particular database, AWS service Database Migration Service can be used if postgres version is higher than 9.4.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html

If postgres version is lower, then only manual export/import of database can be used. Another instance where export files will be stored is needed.